# Pushing a Git repo to Gitorious makes me enter fullpath name

Tags: git, server, gitorious

We have a Gitorious server on an internal network. When I create a repo using the web interface at say myproject/myrepo.git, Gitorious instructs me to go into my folder of source code, and then:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first timer"
git remote add origin git@myservername:myproject/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

When I do this, it errors out telling me,

```
"fatal: 'myproject/myrepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository"
"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"
```

I can solve this problem by inputting the full pathname

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@myservername:/opt/gitorious-3.1.1-1/apps/gitorious/repositories/myproject/myrepo.git
```

but I would rather not have to do this. It seems like something somewhere should know to where to point the git protocol, along the lines of how an apache server knows to find documents in the htdoc folder or something. I have a feeling this is neither a problem with git or gitorious, but with something lower on the software stack.

My question is how do I fix this? Where would this setting be? What is the topic for which I should search in a google?

Comment: So I have done some further investigation. The above noted information is   based on observations when using an Ubunto Machine. I have a windows machine which suffers the same problem, but we have several machines that don't suffer this problem. That is to say that git clone git@myserver:myproj/myrepo.git works for my coworkers windows machine, but not for my windows machine (or my ubunto machine)

Answer (score 0):

are you working on the same machine as you repository is?
If you do it make sense and i assume that you did not started any **[`git deamon`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon)**

If you are not using the same server, have you followed **[those instructions](http://getgitorious.com/documentation/admin-guide.html#sec-1-2-2)** here?

Comment: I am not using the same machine. I didn't set up the gitorious server but I did just look through those instructions and they didn't seem to speak to specifying a path

Comment: Read this section 'Installing without direct Internet access'. the git repositories are expected to be found under '/var/www/gitorious/app' which is a different path from the the one you posted here.

Comment: When I use the gitorious web interface, it puts the repositories in /opt/gitorious-3.1.1-1/apps/gitorious/repositories. If git knows to look in the directory that you just specified, how do i tell gitorious to put repositories there?

Comment: first of all verify that its working if you move the repository to this location. if it does work simply create a symbolic link from the current folder to the desired one.

Comment: That didn't work. I had to create the folders www/gitorious/app.

Comment: I think I need to examine the base-path parameter that is passed to git daemon

Comment: I agree. your problem is in the gitosis environment somewhere. since i dont have access to your machine, i cant help you more then that. you will need to fix up your environment.   Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ended up having to regenerate my SSH key. I didn't have any keys in /.ssh, but I never noticed this because it would just ask for my password, and I would enter it and everything would be fine. I generated another ssh key in git using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myname@myserver.com"`, added it to gitorious, and tried again and it didn't work. I then tried `ssh -v git@myserver` and it appeared that it didn't try or perhaps see my custom_name key. I then generated another key, using the default name id_rsa and tried ssh-v again and it appeared to work. I then tried  `git clone git@myserver:myproject\myrepo.git` and everything went off without a hitch.

Curiously, now I can no longer ssh into my server from the git bash prompt; the server responds:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome myname. Use git to push/pull your repositories
Connection closed
```